# Is there a Python equivalent for MATLAB's 'improfile' function?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to produce a Gaussian fit to profile the beam intensity of an image of a laser beam cross-section. I know how to do this easily with MATLAB's `improfile` function, which lets me specify the line segment with my mouse and plots the intensity values versus the distance along the line segment. Is there a Python equivalent that will let me complete the same task?

Comment: Why not just import `matplotlib` for Python?

Comment: @Cygnus. Because that by itself is so far from being a solution as to be almost irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is: Function [`profile_line`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.profile_line) from the `skimage.measure` package. I do not have the Image Processing Toolbox in MATLAB, so I cannot show the example also with MATLABs `improfile` function, but it works the same way as `skimage`s `profile_line`.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import profile_line
from skimage import io

# Load some image
I = io.imread('265173ab144040477cc4d41606b36cd6.jpg', as_gray=True)

# Extract intensity values along some profile line
p = profile_line(I, (45, 30), (160, 30))

# Extract values from image directly for comparison
i = I[45:161, 30]

plt.plot(i)
plt.ylabel('intensity')
plt.xlabel('line path')
plt.show()
```

In the profile intensity plot, both arrays are ontop of each other

[image]

Proof:

```
>>> np.array_equal(p, i)
True
```